# How to implement Cache.Add and Cache.Get in .NET Core project

Tags: .net, caching, .net-core

How to implement System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Add and System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Get in .NET Core project . .NET Core not supporting System.Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the middleware **services.AddMemoryCache();** then you have to inject "**IMemoryCache**" to the place you want to set/get cache. With the instance of IMemoryCache  you can set and get cache. Please find the documentation below,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2